# Get Remote SQL Server Date/Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the current time of a remote server running SQL Server 2012 from a client machine. I have this SQL code:

```
Select SYSDATETIME() as ServerTime
```

I thought this was exactly what I wanted and since I was using a development machine with my own SQL Server, it worked fine because I never thought the time I got was my own computer time. Then I found out this doesn't work if I wanted the remote machine's date/time. Is there anyway I can get the remote server's date/time when my application starts up? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any error message or why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: "Returns a datetime2(7) value that contains the date and time of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running." - it should work.

Comment: why dont you use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Maybe you should consider TimeZone too.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your comments. I have a client computer without SQL Server installed, just the connectivity components so it can connect to the server. I added this code, it returns an error which is the same error as when the Server is not configured to allow remote connections. I removed the SQL statement and everything worked well. I could query information against the server's database. I don't really know why it happened this way :(

Comment: @zzlalani In my situation, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and SYSDATETIME() end up having the same result.

Comment: So, `Select SYSDATETIME() as ServerTime` gives you "not configured for remote connections", but replacing that statement with say `select 'hello'` gives you no error?

Comment: Have you tested this repeatedly? Maybe it was just a temporary network issue, and it was just a coincidence that it started working when you removed the statement.

Comment: Select SYSDATETIME() as ServerTime gives me "not configured for remote connections" and using select with tables involved does not give me errors...yeah that's it. I, unfortunately have tested this for 2 whole days and I have tried removing the code and readding it more than 5 times...It's always the same...I have never encountered this error before. I'm going bald thinking...

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm positive it isn't a network issue. I've tested it wirelessly and wired since I'm on LAN, I pinged the server with flawless response :(

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why?

Comment: @Alexander You mean why do I have to get the server time?

Comment: What you're saying just does not make sense. At the point at which a connection is established, it has *no* way to know what statements you're going to be sent on that connection. There's no way for a connection to succeed or fail based on future events. (Or, you've somehow invented a time machine)

Comment: Yes, please, I'm curious.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Exactly Sir, I know it doesn't make sense. It's the reason why I don't know what the problem is...Hold on I'll post a picture of my code and the error.

Comment: @Alexander So all the client computers use the same time (Server time as reference) when Inserting something. Basically I just get the server time when my application starts up then my application continues running the time.

Comment: More code and the error would be appreciated. Posting it as code (copy the code in, highlight the block, and hit `{}`) would be more valued than a picture. It's difficult for us to copy and paste a picture into visual studio and try things out for ourselves.

Comment: Any why not use UTC-Time?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Holy cow I got it to work Sir...It turned out I have a default value of the connection string. I also have a .ini file that contains the server's connection string. And I ended up using the default connection string. The rest of my SQL worked because I've reestablished the server's connection string after getting the server's time. I apologize for all the trouble I've caused. I never wanted to ask this but I just couldn't find the fix until now. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Alexander Because the network computers won't be connected to the Internet :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'SYSDATETIME' AS FunctionName, SYSDATETIME() AS DateTimeFormat
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET', SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SYSUTCDATETIME', SYSUTCDATETIME()
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL
SELECT 'GETDATE', GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 'GETUTCDATE', GETUTCDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SYSUTCDATETIME', SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30')
```

Where `+5:30` is `IST`

**Output:**

[image]

## <kbd>[Sql Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14247)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work. I don't get the problem. I have the same connectionstring, I'm pretty sure of this. I can query against tables but I can't get the Server time :(

Comment: @chris_techno25 i have updated my answer check with that

Comment: May i know what error you got now,  i have again updated my answer!

Comment: Thank you for your help. The SQL statements work fine. My problem is that if I added the statement to get the server time, it gives out an error. If I removed this, it just works. This is the error I have if I added the statement to get the time. "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."

Comment: I'm sorry for all the trouble but I'm really going crazy over this. I have more than 50 other SQL statements that just work against the database and this statement to get the time ruins the whole application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46307/discussion-between-amarnath-balasubramanian-and-chris-techno25)

Comment: Thank you for your help Amarnath. I got it to work. My SQL statement works fine. I just misread my code and it used my dummy connection string before it executed the SQL statement... I appreciate your help very much. I'm sorry for all the trouble. I'll vote your answer up ;)

Answer (score 1):

Holy cow I got it to work everyone...It turned out I have a default value of the connection string. I also have a .ini file that contains the server's connection string. And I ended up using the default connection string. The rest of my SQL worked because I've reestablished the server's connection string after getting the server's time. I apologize for all the trouble I've caused. I never wanted to ask this but I just couldn't find the fix until now. Thank you for all your help.